# Best way to print a datagridview with all rows and all columns?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I need to add some functionality to be able to print whatever is displayed in datagridview. I tried to use bitmap class but it does not seem to be printing all the rows and columns. It looks like a screenshot and missing some columns and rows.
Anybody knows any better way to handle this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are some examples/utilities on CodeProject:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/PrintingOfDataGridView.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/GridPrintPreviewSolution.aspx
  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/GridPrintPreviewSolution2.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/DGVPrinter.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the examples. The code is certainly helpful. I will choose one of the ways to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link :

[How To Print a Data Grid in C# and .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/HowToPrintaDataGridinCsHARPand.NET11212005060838AM/HowToPrintaDataGridinCsHARPand.NET.aspx)

And Have you tried  creating local report (rdlc and using Reportviewer)?

This will also help you to create custom reports..

Regards

Comment: For some reason, I can't use rdlc. But one of the ways that you suggested will work for me. Thanks again.