# Printing of DataGridView in Winform C#

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am trying to Printing Datagridview by making bitmap image , Its working nicely but it printing only in 1 page to print  .

**Here is DataGirdView Image :**

[image]

**Print Preview Image** :

[image]

Here in print-Preview not having total rows to the last as of DataGridView row and only having 1 page

**Code of Printing** :

```
 private void Btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int height = DGV.Height;
            DGV.Height = DGV.RowCount * DGV.RowTemplate.Height * 2;
            bmp = new Bitmap(DGV.Width, DGV.Height);
            DGV.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, DGV.Width, DGV.Height));
            DGV.Height = height;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();       

        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        }
```

Why not printing data in more than 1 page ? Is there any wrong in code ? Please give suggestion

Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

It's not the easiest thing to print multiple pages from a DataGridView so I recommend you to use one of the existing code samples. Here's couple good ones which are easy to use and can print multiple pages:

- [Another DataGridView Printer](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/printing/dgvprinter.aspx)
- [DataGridView Print/Print Preview Solution](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/printing/gridprintpreviewsolution.aspx)

Some more examples are available from this SO question:

[Best way to print a datagridview with all rows and all columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398354/best-way-to-print-a-datagridview-with-all-rows-and-all-columns)