# C# Datatable values to fit and add page number for printing

Tags: c#, printing, datatable

I am trying to printing of datatable values.I don't know how to print but I found a example for datatable.It's working but values not to fit for print document. And I want to use dynamically for print.I want to headers(with left and right) and add page numbers.
I searched a lot but I could not find anything.
This code for printing datatable

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
        document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(document_PrintPage);

        PrintPreviewDialog ppDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        ppDialog.Document = document;
        ppDialog.Show();
    }

    
    void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument document = (PrintDocument)sender;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Pen pen = new Pen(brush);
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 9);

        int x = 0, y = 0, width = 150, height = 30;

        foreach (DataColumn column in a.Columns)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, width, height);
            SizeF size = g.MeasureString(column.ColumnName, font);
            float xPadding = (width - size.Width) / 2;

            g.DrawString(column.ColumnName, font, brush, x + xPadding, y + 5);
            x += width;
        }


        x = 0;
        y += 30;
        int columnCount = a.Columns.Count;

        foreach (DataRow row in a.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, width, height);
                SizeF size = g.MeasureString(row[i].ToString(), font);
                float xPadding = (width - size.Width) / 2;

                g.DrawString(row[i].ToString(), font, brush, x + xPadding, y + 5);
                x += width;
            }
            x = 0;
            y += 30;
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5398354/14171304

Comment: I tried with datagridview but it doesn't print all of them because datagridview show just one page